# Is it OK to liquid nail drywall in a hard-to-reach corner?

Tags: drywall, adhesive

I need to drywall around an 8" air spiral pipe coming out of a wall at a 45 deg angle and there is very little room on the side between it and the wall the pipe runs parallel to.  So it is very very hard to screw or nail the drywall because there is simply no room to reach with a screwdriver/hammer/drill.

Are there any issues with affixing that piece with [liquid nails](http://www.liquidnails.com/products/wall-adhesive-DWP24)?  I was going to apply some liquid nail on the framing behind and basically glue the drywall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can.  I have my guys use [Liquid Nails](http://www.liquidnails.com/tips/interior-wall-adhesive) for ceilings.  We still add screws but not really sure you HAVE TO.  Definitely nothing wrong with using the correct adhesive for a few studs on a piece of drywall.

Comment: one subquestion:  you think i should go for the special drywall liquid nails ($9+ @ Amazon) or is the regular liquid nails from Home Depot is OK ?

Comment: I am guessing the special drywall stuff soaks in better where when using the regular it hardens up on the surface.  If it is just one stud I don't think it matters.

Comment: Homely Despot does sell drywall adhesive in a tube, too. I forget what I paid, precisely, but I think it was perhaps $45 for a case of 12 (28-oz jumbo caulk/glue tubes), so not anywhere near $9/tube...it's a good supplement to regular screwing (or allows you to reduce the screw schedule, if you want to), too.

Comment: @Ecnerwal - there are several brands now used for drywall.  I know my crew has used the LN version and some other brand.  I will ask them.  They don't like using long (1 1/4 is what they use) so I make them bind the ceilings.

Comment: Longer screws have limited benefit anyway - only so much holding power to a drywall screw **head**, whether the screw is 1 inch long or 3 inches long. I put up 1000 square feet of 5/8 with 1-1/8 screws - and adhesive. It's driving into 1x3 (nominal) strapping across the trusses and I didn't want screw points sticking out all over the place in the attic...adhesive is cheap insurance.

Comment: @Ecnerwal - I agree but inspectors in my area want screws 1 inch plus into framing.  Meaning at least 1.5".  My guys use 1.25"...  So the inspectors have lightened up their stance if I glued first.

Answer (score 0):

Not really an aswer, but I can't put a picture in a comment. Tain't Liquid Nails brand, but here's what Homely has on offer, and it is right around $45/case of 12 (don't recall if they sell it not by the case:)

[image: OSI F-38] Works good, doesn't stink too much (low VOC.)

Comment: is this from the same manufacturer that makes the Quad window and door sealant ?